# How do I partially update a Date / Time picker value?

Tags: material-ui, mui-x

I'm trying to allow partial updates to a date/time picker: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/

The scenario is as follows.. I have a date/time set. And I just want to update the time from AM to PM.

Let's say the starting state is

[image]

If I click PM, it'll update the value in the input box to show PM. But then if you click outside of the popup to close it, it'll revert back to AM.

It looks like the only way to set the date/time is to set every date and time option to update it.

Is there a setting on the component to allow partial updates to the date/time as described, so that when closing the popup, it preserves the update?

Thanks.